# How to get a "new email" counter/badge to the Evolution app icon on Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: 18.04, icons, evolution, ubuntu-dock

Is there a way to add a "new email" counter/badge to the Evolution app icon on Ubuntu Dock? The Thunderbird icon shows a badge/counter/indicator with the new resp. unread messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ryan Hendrickson](https://gitlab.gnome.org/rhendric) and [Milan Crha](https://gitlab.gnome.org/mcrha) have worked on this and it is present in [Evolution with version 3.29.3+](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/issues/9#note_229159). Thanks a lot!

You may have to **install** the package `evolution-indicator` if it is not installed by default, e.g. with Synaptics or in a terminal: `sudo apt install evolution-indicator` (Thank you [Cos64](https://askubuntu.com/users/189834/cos64) for the tip).

This new feature was not **backported** to **Ubuntu 18.04** as expected. But **Ubuntu 19.04** (and later) comes with updated Evolution (3.32.1-2) and the **counter/badge works**.

Comment: Does this work for you? I have Ubuntu 19.04 with Evolution 3.32.1-2 and I don't get badges.

Comment: I had to install the `evolution-indicator` package. Now it works also in my 19.10 (eoan) which is an upgrade from 18.04 LTS (bionic).

Comment: Thank you @Cos64 for your comment!