# No E-Mail Notification Thunderbird in Dock

Tags: thunderbird, notification, 18.10, ubuntu-dock

I have Ubuntu 18.10 and if I get a new E-mail from Thunderbird the red notifier on Dock (button) is not visible.

Have somebody an idea what happens?

Answer (score 1):

In Thunderbird General preferences, check the following setting...

[image]

If you're using the `Dash to Dock` GNOME extension, the email message counter won't display, and this setting should be set to off.

Comment: I don't see the setting "Show in the messaging menu" in my Thunderbird 60.6.1.

Comment: @Filbuntu I have the same version, and I have it. I don't know if it does anything any more though on 19.04 with no Dash-to-Dock GNOME extension.

Comment: I forgot to add that I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and that may explain that I don't see this setting.  
Interestingly the red notifier on the Dock was present a year ago but at some point vanished, not sure why and where to :) .

Answer (score 0):

[Heynnema's solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106988/30631) still does not work for me (Ubuntu 20.04). I have looked into different alternatives which have not convinced me so far.
[**Birdtray**](https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray) is the most suitable alternative for me so far, a new mail system **tray notification** icon for Thunderbird.

I still miss the new Email count/badge/notifier on the Dock (button) like [it was added to Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1050947/30631).